# Not able to use filter operators of rxjs in angular4

Tags: angular, rxjs5, rxjs-pipeable-operators

i am trying to use filter in angular 4, this is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { range } from 'rxjs/observable/range';
import { map, scan, filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {  

  ngOnInit(){
    this.rxjs();
  }
  rxjs(){
    const source$ = range(1, 10);

    source$.pipe(
      filter(n => n % 2 !== 0), 
      tap(n => console.log('filtered value: ' + n)),
      map(n => n * n),
      tap(n => console.log('squared value: ' + n)),
      scan((acc,s) => acc + s, 0)
    )
    .subscribe(v => console.log(`sum of squared values : ${v}`));    
  }    
}
```

this is my angular version, which i found out using **ng --version** command

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.10
node: 8.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.7
@angular/common: 4.4.7
@angular/compiler: 4.4.7
@angular/core: 4.4.7
@angular/forms: 4.4.7
@angular/http: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.7
@angular/router: 4.4.7
@angular/cli: 1.4.10
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.7
@angular/language-service: 4.4.7
typescript: 2.3.4
```

but when i compile, i am getting an error like this

> ERROR in E:/angular-mock/routes/src/app/app.component.ts (19,19): The
>   left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
>   'number' or an enum type.

can anyone help me on what i am doing wrong in this

Comment: Which version of RxJS? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: install rxjs-compat it will work.

Comment: @lijin working example :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-background-tmkeyd

Comment: @ExplosionPills "rxjs": "^5.4.2"

Comment: @programoholic any idea why was this not working in my current version of rxjs, ie. rxjs 5.4.2?

Comment: It looks like there is somewhat of a mixture of RxJS 5 and RxJS 6 syntax. I would guess that is why it is not working. For example, the import statement for your RxJS operators is using the RxJS 6 syntax. But you are using RxJS 5. See this link for more info: https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: @LijinDurairaj because from rxjs 5.x onwards major changes are made . may be syntax got changed.

Comment: @LijinDurairaj i will put it as answer accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to **install** `RxJS` in order to use this library

```
$ npm i rxjs
```

If you need ***backward compatibility*** for older projects or dependencies that not upgraded to version 6 yet use compact too

```
$ npm i rxjs-compat
```

### Read Detailed Migration Guide:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

### Demo:

```
$ npm i rxjs rxjs-compat
```

### See also:

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Answer (score -1):

well i solved the issue by installing
rxjs@6 and installing rxjs-compat@6 for backward compatibility

```
 npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```